# Android app crashing after migrating to Jetpack View Binding (Using BottomNavigationView with Navigation Component)

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation, android-viewbinding, android-navigation-graph

I am migrating an Android app from Kotlin synthetic to Jetpack ViewBinding. App is having
a Bottom Navigation View with Navigation graph setup. But when I try to navigate from the underlying fragment using `findNavController().navigate` method, App crashes and Logcat shows the following crash logs. This started happening after I migrated Main Activity to View Binding.

```
2022-02-21 15:34:44.626 29145-29145/com.x.7 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.x.y, PID: 29145
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:897)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:863)
        ---------
        ---------
        ---------
        ---------
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27340)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

My current setup of the app is as follow:

- activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/screen_background"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/icon_bottom_navigation_bar"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- MainActivity.kt

```
    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val navGraphIds = listOf(
            R.navigation.nav_graph_tab_first,
            R.navigation.nav_graph_tab_second,
            R.navigation.nav_graph_tab_third
        )

        // Setup the bottom navigation view with a list of navigation graphs
        val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            containerId = R.id.fragmentContainerView,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            intent = intent,
            onNavigationItemSelectionChanged = this::handleNavigationItemSelectionChanges
        )

        currentNavController = controller
        currentNavController?.observe(this, { renderNavControllerChanges(it) })
    }
```

FirstTabFragment.kt

```
class FirstTabFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : ViewBindingBaseFragment<VB>() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.clickMe.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detail_fragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Here when the user taps on the Click Me button, App gets crashed with the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node`.

Seem I'm stuck here and can't remove the kotlin-extension plugin due to this crash.